# blazor lifecycle - ensuring the functions are called one after the another

Tags: blazor

I have this razor file dashboard.razor which contains another razor file as a component. userclaims.razor which does some initialisation and getting GetClaimsPrincipalData

### dashboard.razor

```
<UserClaims/>


//some other code
OnInitializedAsync()
//some other code etc., etc.,
```

How do i ensure the Userclaims.razor executes fully and then the OnInitializedAsync() of the dashboard.razor gets called. Is there a way to ensure the order? Coz the Userclaims.razor initialises some basic values which needs to be used in the dashboard.razor's OnInitializedAsync()

How

Comment: If you need components to be rendered prior to the code in `OnInitializedAsync` running, maybe that is the wrong lifecycle event to use. Have you considered using `OnAfterRenderAsync` and then only running your code if `firstRender` is true?

Comment: [Please don't take the wrong way] Have a dependency on data from a sub-component is a crazy idea.  Logic belongs in the Application layer, not the component.  Any logic needs to live in a service (or cascading object) that both the parent and child use.

Answer (score 0):

If you need Claims, you can simply use the CascadingValue. There is no way to achieve what you are asking.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: I understand we need to use claims. I am using that but how do I ensure that the claims are getting initialised fully before the OnInitializedAsync() method is called in the dashboard.razor file

Comment: You can move the claims obtaining logic to a service and obtain them in the OnInitializedAsyc() . Otherwise, if you obtain them in a component higher up and pass as cascading value, then they are guaranteed to be initialized before you call OnInitialized on the child component.